# Can a C# Datatable expression be used with global values?

Tags: c#, datacolumn

I would like to use the DataColumn's expression similar to what Excel allows.

Consider Excel if I have a column 'A'(raw inputs) and another 'a' that is =2*A+$B$1 then each cell in 'a' column takes the corresponding cell in 'A' and multiplies by 2 and adds the value in B1. 
If I change the value in B1 then all the values in 'a' are changed.

Restrictions: The number of data columns is data driven as well as their expressions.

Is there a syntax that allows this?
Can you create a DataColumn with only one row and have all the others reference it?
Is there a way to create a parent table that holds that global value and thus can be referenced?